# How to add a new method to a util class object

Tags: java, graph

I want to implement a class Graph in java:

```
public class Graph {
    LinkedList<String> vertices;
    LinkedList<Tuple<String>> edges;
```

the class Tuple holds pairs of Strings representing a directed edge.
I want to add a method to remove an edge from the graph. I do not know the syntax on how to do that though. I have thought of something like

```
LinkedList<Tuple<String>> edges = new LinkedList<>({
public void removeEdge(Tuple<String> key) { ...}
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure someone will give you a more detailed answer but the short answer is that you cannot modify a class once it is compiled (without bytecode manipulation).  You could extend `Graph` as `MutableGraph` and add your method to the child class.

Comment: As a side note, you've said "add a new method to a util class"; `Graph` is appears to be a bean/pojo/data-object, not a util class.  A util class would typically be stateless perform actions on another type.  If you are indeed looking to create a util class, consider modeling it after this widely used util class: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.3582

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, because you are using a LinkedList from the Java Collections Framework, you could use the built-in remove method.

Here are a couple of places you can go to see if my suggestion would work for your case:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linkedlist-remove-method-in-java/